How to invoke eslint 9.x with flat configuration?
I'm trying to invoke eslint 9.0.0 on the command line after migrating from 8.x for several hours now and have identified the following relevant parameters of which I tried all possible combinations. I had a working setup with 8.x where I used the pre-flat configuration and eslint 'src/**/*.ts'.
My sources are in src/ and they're the only files I want to check. The config file is eslint.config.js.

CLI: eslint, eslint ., eslint 'src/**/*', eslint 'src/**/*.ts'
files and ignores: tried all items of the powerset of  { ignores: ["dist/*", "dist/**/*", "**/dist/**/*", "eslint.config.js", ".yarn/*", ".yarn/**/*"], files: ["**/*.ts", "src/**/*", "src/*", "src/**/*.*"],
adding eslint.config.js to ignores (which apparently is necessary in order to avoid absolutely absurd error messages)

I read the https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide#cli-flag-changes multiple times and found some blog posts, but none of them seem to invoke eslint from the CLI (no idea how to use it then) or want to keep it a secret how to do that.
So far, I get the error
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.0.0

ESLint couldn't find a configuration file. To set up a configuration file for this project, please run: ...

which I guess is because the base dir changes with the dir argument passed on CLI. The docs contain a hint

The --ext flag was used to specify additional file extensions ESLint should search for when a directory was passed on the command line, such as npx eslint .. This is no longer supported when using flat config. Instead, specify the file patterns you’d like ESLint to search for directly in your config. For example, if you previously were using --ext .ts,.tsx, then you will need to update your config file like this:

but this is at least unintuitive because the dir argument still exists and files and ignores have absolutely no effect on anything since if I omit them eslint tries to parse everything in siblings of src/, like *.js file in dist/ or .yarn/ (both the extention don't match and the dirs are excluded).
My config file is
/** @type {import('eslint').Linter.FlatConfig[]} */
const typescriptEslint = require("@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin")
const typescriptParser = require("@typescript-eslint/parser")

const deprecationPlugin = require("eslint-plugin-deprecation")
const importPlugin = require("eslint-plugin-import")
const prettierPlugin = require("eslint-plugin-prettier")
const unicornPlugin = require("eslint-plugin-unicorn")
const globals = require("globals")

module.exports = [
  {
    ignores: ["dist/*", "dist/**/*", "**/dist/**/*", "eslint.config.js", ".yarn/*", ".yarn/**/*"],
    files: ["**/*.ts"],
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2022,
      sourceType: "script",
      parser: typescriptParser,
      parserOptions: {
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
      },
      globals: {
        ...globals.node,
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      "@typescript-eslint": typescriptEslint,
      deprecation: deprecationPlugin,
      import: importPlugin,
      prettier: prettierPlugin,
      unicorn: unicornPlugin,
    },
    rules: { ... },
]

with all mentioned variations.

I think https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/18372 matches my issue. Since there's also no real support for the flat config yet apparently (eslint --init creates a legacy config file, https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/18369), there'll probably tons of other issues.
